# Construct SQL query to find records that all have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table related to reviews made by a person. The table has the following fields: **reviewId**, **personId**, **isComplete**, where **isComplete** is a boolean indicating whether the particular person completed his review.

Imagine the following values:

```
ReviewID | PersonID | isComplete |

   1         1         1
   2         1         1
   3         2         0
   4         2         0
   5         3         1
   6         3         0
```

In this case I should get only **PersonID** = 1 as a result because only they have completed all their reviews.
I have tried many queries and the closest one was:
`SELECT * FROM reviews x WHERE 1 = ALL (SELECT isComplete FROM reviews y WHERE x.personid = y.personid AND isComplete=1);`

Any suggestions or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think of it in terms of sets.  You need a set of data for all people and remove from it a set of people having at least 1 review not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(PersonID) FROM reviews 
WHERE PersonId NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(PersonID) FROM reviews WHERE isComplete = 0
)
```

Answer (score 2):

- Table A contains all records
- Table B contains all people who have at least 1 outstanding review.
- We use a left join and eliminate nulls so that what remains is only users who have records with no outstanding reviews...

.

```
SELECT Distinct A.PersonID 
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN Table B 
 on A.PersonID = B.PersonId
 and B.isComplete = 0
WHERE B.PersonId is null
```

I used distinct to only return 1 records.

Another way to do this (I believe to be the most efficient) would be to use an exists statement

```
SELECT Distinct A.PersonID
FROM table A
WHERE not exists (Select 1 from Table B where B.iscomplete=0 and A.PersonID=B.PersonID)
```

This basically says return all persons who don't have an incomplete review.

The premise in both these cases is that a single entry of an incomplete review is enough to exclude them from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM reviews a WHERE a.PersonId NOT IN
( SELECT b.PersonId FROM reviews b WHERE b.isComplete = 0 )
```

This is getting all the persons that match isComplete = 0 and then only including the persons that aren't in that list.

Comment: thanks very much it worked - I just need the DISTINCT(PersonID) to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: @user3603634, yeah I wasn't sure what you needed from the list since you had `*` in your original query so I just left it how it was.